# How to initialize class in another class

Tags: c++, initialization

I am willing to use make class in which constructor should do nothing but in my class i have declare one more class which takes some argument in the constructor. how can I pass arguments in that class?

Right now i am using constructor like below and it is working fine,

```
 /* some other class */
    OtherClass board;

/*main class in which I have declared OtherClass*/

    MyClass(std::string calibrationFile, std::string task,
                  std::string device, uInt64 numberOfSamples = 1000, float64 samplingRate = 1.0e4):
            board(task, device, numberOfSamples, samplingRate),
            f(6, 0)
        {}
```

but I want to make it like below,

```
MyClass():
    board(Task, Device, NumberOfSamples, SamplingRate),
        f(6, 0)
    {

    }
```

problem is that I dont know how to initialize arguments that I want to pass in board.
kindly guide me how can I do that.

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. I understand the working solution in the first example. In that case, someone who creates a MyClass object has to provide the parameters for creating a board object. In the second examples, I don't understand what `Task`, `Device` and so on are supposed to be. Are these class names? Or are they default values? At what time should these values be decided?

Comment: Task, Device are the arguments that I have to pass in borad but I dont want to pass it using MyClass constructor. is there any alternate way to pass arguments in board?

Comment: If you make `board` a member of `MyClass`, the constructor of `MyClass` is responsible for constructing the `board` member when `MyClass` gets constructed. So the constructor has to know how to construct `board`, which means it has to pass the arguments to the `board` constructor.  On the other hand, constructor arguments to `MyClass` are not the only option, you could use constants, global variables, static members of MyClass, the result of factory functions or singleton getters. It all depends on the problem at hand, but you did not describe it.

Comment: I can't use global variables, let me try to explain, I have a MFC base project in which I declare object of MyClass in SomeClassDlg.h file. I have to make two objects of MyClass in SomeClassDlg.h so if I make MyClass constructor like I have done in first case then I have to pass the arguments in SomeClassDlg that seems to me not possible. I just want to find a way so that I constructor of MyClass should not take any arguments but how to initialze borad in this case?

Comment: If you want to create a `MyClass` object *without* constructing the `board` member while the constructor is running, `board` must not be a data member of `MyClass`. Objects of `OtherClass`, like `board` seem to be unable to be constructed without getting initialized, so you can't construct `board` without initializing it. So if you want to initialize `board` a different time than construction of `MyClass`, don't make it a value member. Other options include a `OtherClass*` pointer member or `boost::optional<OtherClass>`. Both of these can be constructed later.

Answer (score 0):

The first code example you have provided is the right way to do what you want. What's wrong with passing arguments into MyClass? It's constructor does exactly "nothing" but passing arguments into it's member constructor. In the second case the only thing you can achieve is passing default values to board's constructor (i.e. hard-coded).

Comment: yes I can pass default value but I want to pass value at run time, basically I want to know how can I pass value to board? without the help of MyClass constructor?

Comment: @nabeel You can't. Another way to do it is initializing the `board` with value of some global variables, which is doubtely suitable for you. I don't see any other ways to pass run-time data to a function.

Comment: is it possible is c++ to declare some class object in some function of other class?